# Using "OR" logic combined with child selectors in CSS

Tags: css

Is there a concise way in CSS to combine the child selector (`>`) with the OR selector (`,`)?  For example, if I want to select all elements either of class `zip` or class `email` who are children of the element with id `form`, this does not work.

```
#form > .email, .zip
```

This will instead select all elements of class `email` who are children of the element with id `form` and then all elements of class `zip` regardless of their parents.  I know I could do this:

```
#form > .email, #form > .zip
```

But if I have multiple classes under `form` that I want to select this will get unwieldy quite fast.  Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: The most concise way would probably be just to give them both a common class and use that instead. Or you could use something like SASS that'll take care of it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Raw CSS

No there's no good way to concisely generate the same root selector for multiple sub-selections

## Using a pre-processor

CSS preprocessors like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) allow selectors to be nested.

This nested selector

```
#form {
    > .email,
    > .zip {
        ...example...
    }
}
```

will generate:

```
#form > .email,
#form > .zip {
    ...example...
}
```